# Column 'XXX' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

*Estou com problema ao executar a seguinte Query:*

```
 SELECT product_id,
       presentation
FROM Variant
INNER JOIN productCategory ON product_id = product_id
LIMIT 10;
```

***Erro:***

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

como posso resolver usando alias ?

Comment: coloque o nome da tabela na frente da coluna.

Comment: Por mais que seja uma erro bem básico creio  que muita gente recorre para saber o que está acontecendo, +1. Editei a sua pergunta para dá um pouco mais de visibilidade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso acontece quando temos o mesmo nome de coluna em ambas as tabelas, daí ocorre o erro "ambiguous", para que o erro desapareça você deve indicar no seu `select` a qual tabela a coluna pertence.

Veja:

```
SELECT
   Variant.product_id, 
   presentation
FROM Variant 
INNER JOIN productCategory 
ON productCategory.product_id = Variant.product_id 
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim, amigo.

```
SELECT v.product_id, 
       presentation 
FROM Variant v 
INNER JOIN productCategory p 
ON v.product_id = p.product_id LIMIT 10;
```