# Fazer uma consulta em duas tabelas e apresentar a quantidade do grupo que tiver mais registros da chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou precisando fazer uma consulta entre as duas tabelas seguintes:

Tabela Turma:

| id_turma | nome_turma | codigo_turma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1A | 20201AVespertino |
| 2 | 2A | 20202AVespertino |
| 3 | 3A | 20203AVespertino |
| 4 | 4A | 20204AVespertino |
| 5 | 5A | 20205AVespertino |
| 6 | 6A | 20206AVespertino |
| 7 | 7A | 20207AVespertino |
| 8 | 8A | 20208AVespertino |
| 9 | 9A | 20209AVespertino |

Tabela Aluno:

| id_aluno | nome_aluno | sobrenome_aluno | id_turma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cesar | Augusto | 1 |
| 2 | Mario | Nunes | 1 |
| 3 | André | Silva | 1 |
| 4 | Ricardo | Novaes | 1 |
| 5 | Rute | Maria | 2 |
| 6 | Maria | Rita | 2 |
| 7 | Elisa | Melo | 2 |
| 8 | Osmarildo | Souza | 2 |
| 9 | Raimundo | Silva | 3 |

O `SELECT` que estou precisando deveria mostrar este resultado:

| id_turma | nome_turma | codigo_turma | quantidade_aluno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1A | 20201AVespertino | 4 |
| 2 | 2A | 20202AVespertino | 4 |

Eu consegui um `SELECT` que mostra todos os ids da turma com suas respectivas quantidades mas não estou conseguindo filtrar apenas o que tem mais registros.

```
select 
  id_turma, count(id_aluno) AS quantidade_aluno 
from aluno 
group by id_turma;
```

Retornando este resultado:

| id_turma | quantidade de aluno |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |

Mas preciso do resultado envolvendo as duas tabelas e mostrando um resultado com a maior turma ou maiores turmas se tiverem quantidades iguais:

```
SELECT 
  nome_turma, código_turma, COUNT(id_aluno) AS quantidade_aluno 
FROM 
  aluno, turma 
WHERE 
  aluno.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
GROUP BY nome_turma;
```

Com o `SELECT` acima tenho o seguinte resultado:

| name_group | code_group | quantidade_alunos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 A Vespertino | 20201AVespertino | 4 |
| 2 A Vespertino | 20202AVespertino | 4 |
| 3 A Vespertino | 20203AVespertino | 1 |

Da forma como está o segundo `SELECT` está apresentando a quantidade de todas as turmas, mas preciso de um `SELECT` que mostraria apenas as duas primeiras turmas visto que ambas tem a mesma quantidade de alunos e são as turmas que tem mais alunos. E se, por exemplo, houvesse uma outra turma ainda com 5 alunos o `SELECT` deveria retornar apenas esta outra turma.

Assim como no exemplo acima o resultado esperado seria este:

| id_turma | nome_turma | código_turma | quantidade_aluno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 A | 20201AVespertino | 4 |
| 2 | 2 A | 20202AVespertino | 4 |

Mas ainda preciso de que o `SELECT` tenha o `id_turma`, mas como estou colocando um `WHERE` para ligar as duas tabelas (aluno com turma através do `id_turma`) ele rejeita gerando um erro como segue:

```
SELECT 
  id_turma, nome_turma, codigo_turma, COUNT(id_aluno) AS quantidade_aluno 
FROM 
  aluno, turma 
WHERE 
  aluno.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
GROUP BY nome_turma;

ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id_turma' in field list is ambiguous
```

Como a sugestão do colega que comentou o POST, eu coloquei um TOP 1 da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
  nome_turma, codigo_turma, COUNT(id_aluno) AS quantidade_aluno 
FROM 
  aluno, turma 
WHERE 
  aluno.id_turma = turma.id_turma 
GROUP BY nome_turma 
ORDER BY quantidade_aluno DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Resultado:

| nome_turma | codigo_turma | quantidade_aluno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 A Vespertino | 20201AVespertino | 4 |

Mas ainda está sem o `id_turma` pois se colocar o `id_turma` gera o erro citado acima. E com este `LIMIT 1` não mostra outra(s) turmas com a mesma quantidade, mostra apenas o primeiro registro excluindo a(s) outra(s) que tem ou tenham a mesma quantidade.

Comment: é só dar um top 1 (ordenando pela quantidade de alunos decrescente)

Comment: E se houver duas turmas com a mesma quantidade de Alunos? E agora que percebi que ainda preciso do id_turma no select mas na cláusula WHERE está sendo relacionada o id_turma das tabelas Alunos e Turmas, assim gera um erro ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id_group' in field list is ambiguous. Estou ajustando o post para procurar ajudar com esta situação.

Comment: Considerando os dados apresentados você tem 4 "Maria Rita", já que cada uma das 4 possui um `id_aluno` diferente, então o resultado exibido não deveria ser: `| 1 A | 20201AVespertino | 4 |  | 2 A | 20202AVespertino | 4 |` (4 e não 1 na segunda linha)?

Comment: Desculpe eu editei a lista incorretamente, mas agora segue, o meu problema seria se há duas turmas com a mesma quantidade de alunos deveria mostrar as duas turmas e não apenas a primeira que aparece no select e o exemplo seria de uma turma com quatro alunos e uma com 1 aluno mas com a sugestão do TOP 1 eu tive que exemplificar com duas turmas com a mesma quantidade para melhorar o select

Comment: Acredito que esse erro `'id_turma' in field list is ambiguous` esta ocorrendo porque as tabelas `aluno` e `turma` tem uma coluna `id_turma` então o SELECT não sabe de qual tabela ele deve retornar esse dado.

Comment: Relacionado: [Column 'XXX' in field list is ambiguous](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262424/3774)

Answer (score -1):

Creio que esta query atenda a suas necessidades:

```
WITH 
    Qtd_Turmas AS (
        SELECT 
          id_turma, COUNT(id_aluno) AS qtd 
        FROM 
          Aluno 
        GROUP BY id_turma
    ),
    Max_Turmas AS (
        SELECT 
          id_turma, MAX(qtd) AS max_qtd 
        FROM
          Qtd_Turmas)
    )
    
SELECT 
  T.id_turma, T.nome_turma, T.codigo_turma, MT.max_qtd
FROM 
  Turma T 
INNER JOIN Max_Turmas MT 
  ON (T.id_turma = MT.id_turma)
```

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mais parece ter um `)` a mais em `Qtd_Turmas)`